PDFjam on oracle 8
I want to scale a pdf on oracle 8, for that I installed the tex-live packages to get pdfjam.
But when I tried to use it in the commandline, it told me that the command pdfjam was not found.
After searching the packages dnf has installed I found nothing that would indicate pdfjam was installed.
I then tried to fnd the package of tex-live that contained pdfjam, but couldnt find anything for oracle 8.9.
Is there any way of getting pdfjam running on oracle 8.9?
